# Multiple publishers and locations with biber/biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber

I want to cite a book which has two different publishers (for the same edition), each with its own location, and I want the bibliography to reflect that.

I am using biber/biblatex.

Can this be accomplished? (Hopefully without too much of a hassle nor hacks like putting a \\ in the publisher field.)

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{blabla.bib}

\begin{document}
    Some silly things can be found in \cite{SP}.
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

plus

```
@book{SP,
    title = {On silly matters},
    author = {Fubus McBogus},
    year = 1337,
    publisher = {Neverland Publishing House, Neverland \& Mirror Press, Wonderland}
}
```

or

```
@book{SP,
    title = {On silly matters},
    author = {Fubus McBogus},
    year = 1337,
    publisher = {Neverland Publishing House and Mirror Press},
    location = {Neverland and Wonderland}
}
```

Comment: You should cite the one you used. Otherwise. please provide a minimum working example (MWE) people can play with.

Comment: If you really need to do this, the simplest way is to just put the two locations in the location field separated by 'and' and do the same for the publisher. In `authoryear` style, this will be printed as "Location A and Location B: Publisher A and Publisher B" which is perfectly clear.

Comment: @AlanMunn: Well, it's not like "I really need to do this" -- I just want to have the correct bibliographic data in the bibliography. Is this such a strange thing to ask?

Comment: @tomasz Is this a question about how to get `biblatex` to do this, or a question about what the "correct" form is for formatting? If it's the latter, the question is off topic, since what counts as "correct" is dependent on your field and more specifically the journal or press style that is required.  If you want a generic way to do this that is clear and understandable, then the second way is better: it keeps publisher information separated from location, and will allow them each to be placed in the right place by different styles.  Mixing them in the publisher field will screw this up.

Comment: It is about the former, just with two variants of not-really-solutions that I can think of. The publisher will do it the way they want to anyway, this is more for "personal" use (as in for a preprint server) and curiosity about the (existence of a) "correct" solution.

Comment: Is the typesetting of the two publishers identical? Is the pagination the same? Can you be sure there are no errors in one not present in the other? No differences in style? Citing the work you consulted is, in my opinion, the clearest option. If the publisher publishes in different places, that's one thing. But different publishers seems different to me and not making clear whose version you used just muddies things for the reader.

Comment: @cfr: You are misunderstanding. This is a *single* book (as in, physical copy) with *two* publishers listed. Not two distinct issues of the same work.

Comment: In that case, I'd just use `and` as you would for `author`. That's what I do if there are say, 2 addresses of equal prominence. I've not had a book with 2 publishers so I'm afraid that I did, indeed, misunderstand you. Sorry about that.

Comment: @cfr: No harm done. That is what I'm going to do, I guess (although "and" in the author field has a special meaning, which it will not have in other fields, so it is not exactly optimal).

Comment: `and` has the same special meaning in the `publisher` and `location` fields as in the `author` field. They are all of data type *list* which means the `and` is treated as a delimiter. `author` is a *name* list which means the individual items are then split further into name parts. `publisher` and `location` are not so the items are not split further. But the special function of `and` is the same in all three.

Comment: @cfr: I see. Thanks for clearing that up. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that the best way to do this is to coordinate the publisher fields with 'and' and separately coordinate the location fields with 'and' in your `.bib` entry (i.e., the second option).

For example, in the standard `authoryear` style, the location precedes the publisher and the two are separated by a colon.  If you choose to eliminate the location field, and add the location into the publisher field, the dual publisher items will not be formatted correctly because they won't match the format of single publisher items.  But if you keep the publishers and locations separately, they will be.

`biblatex` is prepared for this, since it treats publishers and locations as multi-element lists.  Depending on the style, the separator will then be different. For example, in the Chicago style, locations are separated by 'and' but publishers are separated by '/'.  (See image below.)

This kind of paired coordination is quite common; (it's often marked with the term "respectively" in English) and so from a linguistic point of view, an item formatted in the second way will be completely understandable in the way intended.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{SPbad,
    title = {On silly matters},
    author = {Fubus McBogus},
    year = 1337,
    publisher = {Neverland Publishing House, Neverland \& Mirror Press, Wonderland}
}

@book{SPgood,
    title = {On silly matters},
    author = {Fubus McBogus},
    year = 1337,
    publisher = {Neverland Publishing House and Mirror Press},
    location = {Neverland and Wonderland}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\parencite{SPbad,SPgood}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

**`authoryear` style**

[image: output of code]

**`biblatex-chicago`**

[image]